# how to handle html in a URl in php?

Tags: php, html, url

I have passing some contents to facebook share url. Which contains some html also.

The problem is it cannot handle the html, When I write , it displays it instead of bolding the text in these tags.

So How will I handle it? I use htmlentities(), htmlspecialcharacters(), and urlencode() but could not solved the problem.

Comment: Where are you sending this code? where is it received?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and do something like:

```
$link = '<a href="http://www.example-site.com/index.html">link-text</a>';
$encoded = urlencode($link);
```

Comment: As mentioned in my above comment, I have used the urlencode() but did not work

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question and comment correctly, you want to show a bold text instead of the HTML itself.

So, if you are showing the HTML by doing `urlencode()` that means the encode is one to many, try without the `urlencode()`

If that doesn't work, then probably HTML is not supported there.